# с++ массив строк

Tags: c++

нужно написать код на языке с++, в котором с консоли вводится парное количество строк, затем с каждой парной строки удаляются все слова, которые встречаются в предыдущей строке. Я пока далеко от решения. Пока что-то в духе:

```
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int const a = 8;

void cut(char s[a][30])
{
    char delimeters[] = " .,";
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= a; i += 2)
    {
        char* word = strtok(s[i], delimeters);
        char* prev_word = strtok(s[i - 1], delimeters);
        while (word != nullptr)
        {
            while (prev_word != nullptr)
            {
                prev_word = strtok(nullptr, delimeters);
                int parameter = strcmp(word, prev_word);
                if (parameter == 0)
                {
                    cout << "function to delete" << endl;
                }
            }
            word = strtok(nullptr, delimeters);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    char text[a][30];
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter string " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin.getline(text[i], 30);
    }
    cut(text);
}
```

На условие в if не обращайте внимание, потом допишу. Пока так, потому что нужно хоть как-то контролировать правильность. Проблема в том, что при условии наличия в двух строках одинаковых слов я в конце должен хоть раз получить строку function to delete, а ее нет. В то же время появляется вот такое вот чудо:[image: введите сюда описание изображения].
Посоветуйте что-нибудь, пожалуйста

Comment: Тут по ходу нужно strstr() применять. Она ищет в строке подстроку, и если находит возвращает указатель на неё.

Answer (score 0):

Пролема возникает из-за двух ошибок.

Первая: (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok) функция strtok содержит в себе статическую переменную buffer, которой присваивается значение входной строки, если она ненулевая. Проблема в том, что эта static переменная одна для всех вызовов функции, т.е. когда вы после word присваиваете priv_word strtok, вы по сути предыдущее значение (s[i]) затираете.

Вторая: У вас во втором цикле `prev_word = strtok(nullptr, delimeters);` идёт перед сравнением строк, из-за чего не учитывается первое слово или же, если строка состоит из одного слова, сравнение идёт с nullptr и возникает ошибка

Возможный вариант исправленного кода:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

class StrTok {
    char* buffer;

public:
    StrTok(): buffer(nullptr) {}

    char* strtok(char* str, const char* delim) {    
        if (str)
            buffer = str;

        buffer += std::strspn(buffer, delim);
    
        if (*buffer == '\0')
            return nullptr;
    
        char* const tokenBegin = buffer;
    
        buffer += std::strcspn(buffer, delim);
    
        if (*buffer != '\0')
            *buffer++ = '\0';
    
        return tokenBegin;
    }
};

template<size_t N, size_t M>
void cut(char (&s)[N][M])
{
    StrTok st1, st2;
    char delimeters[] = " .,";

    for (size_t i = 1; i < N; i += 2)
    {
        char* word = st1.strtok(s[i], delimeters);
        char* prev_word = st2.strtok(s[i - 1], delimeters);

        while(word) {
            while (prev_word) {
                int parameter = strcmp(word, prev_word);
                if (!parameter) {
                    // Здесь могла быть ваша реклама ;)
                }
                prev_word = st2.strtok(nullptr, delimeters);
            }

            word = st1.strtok(nullptr, delimeters);
            prev_word = st2.strtok(s[i - 1], delimeters);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 4, M = 30;
    char text[N][M];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter string " << i + 1 << ": ";
        std::cin.getline(text[i], M);
    }

    (void) cut(text);
}
```